# jQuery if Location.Pathname contains

Tags: jquery, url, pathname

I am currently using the following code to target individual pages such as *http://my-website.com/about/*

```
    if (document.location.pathname == "/about/") {
        //Code goes here
    }
```

I am wondering how to do the same for all pages that have a certain parent page such as `/about/`in the following examples..

http://my-website.com/about/child-page1

http://my-website.com/about/child-page2

Answer (score 22, accepted):

use indexOf - it will test true for all pathnames starting with `/about/`

```
if (document.location.pathname.indexOf("/about/") == 0) {
    //Code goes here
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
    if (document.location.pathname.indexOf("/about/") === 0) {
        //Code goes here
    }
```

This will check to make sure the `pathname` always starts with that string.  If you are interested in checking the format more specifically, you will need to use `regex`.

Answer (score 0):

A bit neat picky but for future references it's safer to check against `-1`:

```
  if (document.location.pathname.indexOf('/about') > -1) {
    // your Code
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to use .includes:

```
if (document.location.pathname.includes('/about')) {
// your Code
}
```